# Kicad: Are these traces all connected (if on same layer)?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, kicad

I'm a kicad newbie and I'm attempting to do two things:

1. keep my layers to a minimum (only 2) to keep cost down
2. allowing kicad to draw the lines for me.

I'm drawing all of my traces on but the auto-connector seems to want to connect each node on it's own, which seems fine for all of the red lines in the image (since those are all VDD).

However, as I begin to add the SCL line (shown as green) I'm assuming that :

- If it is on the same layer then those traces would be considered connected in every location where they cross the red line.  Is that assumption correct?

[image: pcb traces in kicad]

Also, are lines that travel through holes connected even if before there is a device added to the hole?  IE - does the connection continue around the hole pad and to the next node?

If it is true that my green line will be electrically connected to the red lines, then :

Does it mean I need to draw my VDD lines all around the edges and make sure they don't touch other items -- just as I would in any other circuit?  As I said that it seems obvious that the answer is yes.

Comment: Ugg! Autorouters! Just say no! I doubt those traces would pass any DRC (Design Rule Check.) Many of them are in contact with the annular rings of plated through holes. I doubt that's intentional. Just learn to route manually. I find it fun and satisfying.

Comment: Just a small comment, Push and shove is much much better than any autorouter programs out there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Red lines will be on one layer, green on the other.  The yellow pads will be on all layers.  Lines of the same colour that cross or touch will be connected together.

Don't use the auto-router - even a novice can do a better job than it.  The lines running diagonally between/across pads will connect to those pads (or will have insufficient clearance from the pads)

Route manually, with the DRC function enabled - DRC will warn if you place tracks too close to pads, or too close to a track belonging to another net.

The program will initally show "air lines" indicating required connections - use the air lines only as a guide to what has to be connected - DO NOT blindly follow the air lines when placing tracks!

Comment: Marking as answer because you answered all my questions exactly as I needed.  Thanks very much for your help.